# Finding the maximum value of an integral

Tags: integration, maxima-minima

The question at hand is to find the maximum value of the integral:

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} |x-a| \cdot e^{x} dx $$

under the constraint that $ |a| \leq 1$

The way I thought of approaching this problem would be to:

$$ f(a) = \int_{-1}^{a} |x-a| \cdot e^{x} dx + \int_{a}^{1} |x-a| \cdot e^{x} dx $$

Then using the fact that $$ |x| =  \begin{cases} 
      x & x\geq 0 \\
      -x & x < 0 
   \end{cases} $$, we can write:

$$ f(a) = \int_{-1}^{a} (a-x) \cdot e^{x} dx + \int_{a}^{1} (x-a) \cdot e^{x} dx $$

Now I am thinking of evaluating the integral using the fact that:

$$ \int (x-\alpha) \cdot e^{x} dx = e^{x}(x-\alpha-1) + C$$

And then I can differentiate with respect to $a$ and try to find the maxima and minima.

It would be great if anyone could tell me if this **approach** is **correct**.

Any **other** interesting approaches would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can take the derivative without transformations you made, just using the fact, that $(|x|)'= \operatorname{sign}(x)$. So,
$$
f'(a)=\int_{-1}^1 \operatorname{sign}(a-x)e^x = \int_{-1}^a e^x - \int_a^1 e^x.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $|a-x| e^x$ is a convex function of $a$ for each $x$, $f(a)$ is a convex function of $a$.  Therefore the maximum must occur at one of the endpoints.  Just calculate $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ to see which it is.